# Reducing memory requirements of a pyomo model

Tags: python, memory, pyomo, reducing

I am building a big pyomo model with over 1 million constraints and 2 million variables.

And I am looking for suggestions to reduce the memory requirements of the model that I am building.

At the moment it requires over `20gb`'s of RAM.

How would I reduce this?

I've never tested defining variables with/without `within=pyomo.NonNegativeReals`. But I am assuming it would reduce the amount of memory required for a given variable. Is there other things I could do without reducing the amount of the variables or constraints.

**Eg:**

Following `var` will need `X` bytes of memory

```
m.var = pyomo.Var(
    m.index)
```

And maybe following will need `X-1` bytes of memory

```
m.var = pyomo.Var(
    m.index,
    within=pyomo.NonNegativeReals)
```

Of course this is a speculation. Without testing one cannot be sure about this. However, I am willing to try anything if some1 has an idea or more experience regarding this issue.

Any ideas?

**Some Tests:**

Keep in mind that is not the real model but the example builded with an other data. But still the same script.

```
index=1000 // Full Consts         // 347580 KB (commit) // 370652 KB (working set)
              0 Const Full Rules  // 282416 KB (commit) // 305252 KB (working set)
              0 Const 0 Rule      // 282404 KB (commit) // 305200 KB (working set)
              1 Const 1 Rule      // 290408 KB (commit) // 313136 KB (working set)

index=8760 // Full Consts         // 1675860 KB (commit) // 1695676 KB (working set)
```

Comment: Is your model flat (i.e., it only consists of a top-level `ConcreteModel` or `AbstractModel`) or does it consist of many `Block` objects?

Comment: @GabeHackebeil it only consist of a `ConcreteModel`, it is actually building the same variables for given `m.index`, and if you optimize for 1h, the index will be 1. however if you optimize for a year index will be 1 to 8760 which ofc increases the amount of vars and constraints...

Comment: I can point you to an alternative interface that has a way of expressing linear constraints using less memory, but first I want to make sure you are not expressing the constraint rows as dense expressions when they can be sparse. Can you narrow the bulk of the memory usage down to a particular indexed constraint (by commenting out everything else)?

Comment: Well not every constraint has the same index, however in many cases, the constraints consist the time index which makes the model fat... I will try to narrow the model, and try to get mem usage of 1 constraint(with indexes) and add it here... Btw is there an easy way to check the memory of the created model? better than checking the task manager

Comment: You can look into packages like `pympler`, but the task manager is probably the faster route.

Comment: @GabeHackebeil I added some test results. Let me know if u need other tests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190455/discussion-between-gabe-hackebeil-and-oakca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `pympler` to analyze the test case you pointed me to. Here is what I've found:

After `pyomo_model_prep` (loads data and places it onto empty `ConcreteModel`):

1. memory usage is 13.2 MB

After adding all `Set` and `Param` objects:

2. memory usage is 13.3 MB

After adding all `Var` objects:

3. memory usage is 14.3 MB

After adding all `Constraint` objects:

4. memory usage is 15.0 MB

When I set the timesteps to 60, the results are

1. memory usage is 13.2 MB (data)
2. memory usage is 13.3 MB (after sets, params)
3. memory usage is 19.6 MB (after vars)
4. memory usage is 23.6 MB (after constraints)

So the variables do have a pretty big impact on model memory when there are a larger number of timesteps. The only obvious place I can see for reducing memory usage is to not store all of the data on the model (or delete it from the model after it is no longer needed), then perhaps what is unused will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Unfortunately, there isn't really any easy way to reduce the memory of the variable declarations.

Update 1: Just an FYI, pretty much all of the memory usage for the variable declarations is a result of the `e_pro_in` and `e_pro_out` indexed variables.

Update 2: If a large number of indices of the `e_pro_in` and `e_pro_out` variables are not used in the model, you can reduce memory requirements by building a reduced index set for each of them. Here is how that might look:

```
e_pro_in_index = []
for t in m.tm:
    for i,j in m.pro_tuples:
        for c in m.com:
            if ...:
                e_pro_in_index.append((t,i,j,c))
m.e_pro_in_index = Set(dimen=4, initialize=e_pro_in_index)
m.e_pro_in = pyomo.Var(
    m.e_pro_in_index,
    within=pyomo.NonNegativeReals,
    doc='Power flow of commodity into process (MW) per timestep')
```

You would need to extract the logic from constraint rules to figure out what indices are not needed.

Comment: A question though is there a way to remove some specific indexes of `e_pro_in` and `_out` after creating all the indexes, because they are `stale=True`?

Comment: If you know ahead of time (before the solve) which indices will be stale, you should build a reduced index set for those variables. I'll add an example to the answer. Doing it after the solve insn't really going to help you reduce peak memory usage.